IISAdministration: How to add the first element to a non-existing ConfigCollection?
My problem:
I try to add a first rewrite rule to a website.
The ConfigurationSection for rules has the path "system.webServer/rewrite/rules", and it has, according to the schema, an unnamed ConfigurationCollection attached. That collection contains the rules.
Initially (upon fresh, unchanged installation of IIS, ARR and rewrite), it is uninitialized:
from applicationHost.config:
<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="system.webServer">
    <sectionGroup name="rewrite">
        <section name="globalRules" overrideModeDefault="Deny" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" />
        <section name="rules" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
        <section name="outboundRules" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
        <section name="providers" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
        <section name="rewriteMaps" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
        <section name="allowedServerVariables" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </sectionGroup>
</Configsections>

There is no web.config at this time, so applicationHost.config has to contain the rules section.
If I try to Get-IISConfigCollection from above section:
$rulesSection = Get-IISConfigSection -SectionPath "system.webServer/rewrite/rules" # succeeds
$rulesCollection = $rulesSection | Get-IISConfigCollection # returns uninitialized

... and now, I would have to add the rule as an element using the New-IISConfigCollectionElement command, which fails because the Collection does not exist.
So, the question is:
How can I get this collection initialized, or what is the correct way to add the collection and a first ConfigCollectionElement in it?

Try $collection = Get-IISConfigSection -SectionPath "system.webServer/rewrite" |Get-IISConfigCollection rules

@MathiasR.Jessen - sorry, no good:
PS > $rs = Get-IISConfigSection -sectionpath "system.webServer/rewrite"
Get-IISConfigSection : Config section 'system.webServer/rewrite' does not exist.
At line:1 char:7

$rs = Get-IISConfigSection -sectionpath "system.webServer/rewrite"

  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-IISConfigSection], ArgumentException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.IIS.Powershell.Commands.GetIISConfigSectionCommand




Try executing this command as administrator, does it work for you?

Hi @XudongPeng - I am the administrator, so no, it does not work for me. The problem is that rewrite is not a section, but a section group. rules is both a section as well as a collection.

I tried executed the command line you provided in the thread, it works fine. So I‘m also confused about this issue. Do you have the same problem on other machines?
